# tabbing environment with no surrounding vertical space

Tags: enumerate, itemize, tabbing, vspace

This probably applies to `tabbing`, `enumerate` and `itemize` blocks, if not others.

How to get rid of (or specify) the default vertical spacing that "wraps" / surrounds the block of items? Normally I want this, as it looks nice. But for some proofs, I want the entire block of lines to have the same vertical spacing as lines around the block.

So for an example of a given `tabbing` block, such as this:

```
\begin{tabbing}
$f \in ND ~~~\= \iff \varphi_f(x)<x$ \quad \quad \quad \= by definition of $ND$ \\
$\varphi_f(x)<x \> \iff \varphi_g(x)<x$ \> by our assumption of $Range(\varphi_f) = Range(\varphi_g)$ \\
$\varphi_g(x)<x \> \iff g \in ND$ \> by definition of $ND$
\end{tabbing}
```

This result is the default, but I don't want this extra vertical spacing around the block:

[image]

Comment: Ok, will do. Have done it before. Didn't think it was that necessary for this question. I even thought that someone would yell at me, so I should have c/p it in. Will do it now... Thank you.

Comment: Question edited w/ code. Given my question though, any `enumerate`, `itemize`, `tabbing` block will give the same result by default that I am trying to avoid. My code was just an example of something in my document. A very simple `tabbing` example would also work.

Comment: Ok, I will completely rewrite this question... Should I delete this one first? My document is way to long to pick apart. I guess you need me to post a very minimal version of a document with a single `tabbing` block in it.

Comment: Well, which documentclass does your document use? Add it to the code snippet. Copy that into a file `mwe.tex` and compile. You get errors. Correct them by copying the relevant packages you load in your original document. Please do not just copy all used packages, only that one relevant to this issue. This art of creating a MWE (minimal working example) helps you and us to understand your issue.

Comment: how's that look? any clearer what I'm looking for?

Comment: OMG! Dude, what's your problem? I posted a complete minimal example for you. The question is about spacing around a `tabbing` or `enumerate` or `itemize` block. Any example of one will do. The answer provided by @Mico works just fine, no mater what is in the block.

Comment: @delrocco - Future readers of this query would likely be very confused if the code in your example only vaguely resembles what's used in the answer(s). Since your initial code apparently "worked" for me, no real need to change it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use either an `array` or a `tabular` environment.

First the `array`-based solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\DeclareMathOperator' macro
\usepackage{array}    % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\Range}{\mathit{Range}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcommand{\ND}{\mathit{ND}}

\begin{document}
Assume $\Range(\varphi_f)=\Range(\varphi_g)$.

$\begin{array}{@{}l@{}l@{\qquad}L@{}}
f\in\ND &{}\iff\varphi_f(x)<x & by definition of $\ND$ \\
\varphi_f(x)<x &{}\iff\varphi_g(x)<x &  by our assumption of $\Range(\varphi_f)=\Range(\varphi_g)$ \\
\varphi_g(x)<x &{}\iff g\in\ND & by definition of $\ND$\\
\end{array}$

This weak form of \dots
\end{document}
```

Second, with the preamble material given above, it's just as easy to achieve your formatting objective by employing a `tabular` environment. All you'd need to change is to replace

```
$\begin{array}{@{}l@{}l@{\qquad}L@{}}
```

with

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}L@{}L@{\qquad}l@{}}
```

and to replace `\end{array}$` with `\end{tabular}`.